# Paypal Subscriptions Pass subscriber info

Tags: javascript, php, paypal

well I created a plan under paypal, and it generates a link to subscribe:
https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/webapps/billing/plans/subscribe?plan_id=PLAN_ID

it works great, but how can I pass the client ID or a custom variable to identify who is subscribing to it?

Answer (score 0):

Using a link there does not appear to be a way, but if you [create a subscribe button that passes a plan](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/subscriptions/integrate/#create-the-subscription) in the `createSubscription` function, you can include a `custom_id` variable there as well.

```js
paypal.Buttons({
  createSubscription: function(data, actions) {
    return actions.subscription.create({
      'plan_id': 'P-###.....',
      'custom_id': '.....'
    });
  },
  onApprove: function(data, actions) {
    alert('You have successfully created subscription ' + data.subscriptionID);
  }

}).render('#paypal-button-container');
```